# Is it possible to get the function behind active binding?

Tags: r

In R, we can use `makeActiveBinding` to create an active binding by supplying a function:

```
e <- new.env()
makeActiveBinding("var", 
  function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n"), e)
```

Once the active binding is created, there seems no way of getting the function behind it.

I wonder if it is possible to get the function behind the active binding like the following?

```
> getActiveBindingFunction("var", e)
function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n"), e)
```

Comment: I've always wanted to do a PR to R core. This might be the best excuse to try one :-)

Comment: KunRen, is there any reason you have not accepted either of the answers to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *R 4.0.0* you can directly use `activeBindingFunction()`. It's not really documented but is straightforward enough!

```r
e <- new.env()
makeActiveBinding("var", 
                  function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n"), e)
activeBindingFunction("var", e)
#> function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer goes out to hrbrmstr. You can coerce the environment to the list then access the function. Please see the code below:

```
e <- new.env()
makeActiveBinding("var", function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n"), e)
as.list(e)$var
```

Ouput:

```
function(x) if (missing(x)) cat("get\n") else cat("set\n")
```

Comment: Note that by default `as.list` uses `all.names = FALSE` so the above will fail for active bindings whose names starts with a dot (`.`). To fix this, use `as.list(e, all.names = TRUE)`.